# How can I normalize data in a pandas dataframe to the starting value of a time series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to analyze a dataset from a clinical study using pandas.
Patients come at different visits to the clinic and some parameters are measured. I would like to normalize the bloodparameters to the values of the first visit (baseline values), i.e: Normalized = Parameter[Visit X] / Parameter[Visit 1].
The dataset looks roughly like the following example:

```py
    import pandas as pd 
    import numpy as np
    rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Patient': ['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
                       'Visit': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                       'Parameter': rng.randint(0, 100, 9)},
                       columns = ['Patient', 'Visit', 'Parameter'])
    df

       Patient  Visit   Parameter
    0    A        1     44
    1    A        2     47
    2    A        3     64
    3    B        1     67
    4    B        2     67
    5    B        3     9
    6    C        1     83
    7    C        2     21
    8    C        3     36
```

Now I would like to add a column that includes each parameter normalized to the baseline value, i.e. the value at Visit 1. The simplest thing would be to add a column, which contains only the Visit 1 value for each patient and then simply divide the parameter column by this added column. However I fail to create such a column, which would add the baseline value for each respective patient. But maybe there are also one-line solutions without adding another column.

The result should look like this:

```py
       Patient  Visit   Parameter Normalized
    0    A        1     44          1.0
    1    A        2     47          1.07
    2    A        3     64          1.45
    3    B        1     67          1.0
    4    B        2     67          1.0
    5    B        3     9           0.13
    6    C        1     83          1.0
    7    C        2     21          0.25
    8    C        3     36          0.43
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html)

```
df['Normalized'] = df['Parameter'].div(df.groupby('Patient')['Parameter']
                                         .transform('first'))
print(df)
  Patient  Visit  Parameter  Normalized
0       A      1         44    1.000000
1       A      2         47    1.068182
2       A      3         64    1.454545
3       B      1         67    1.000000
4       B      2         67    1.000000
5       B      3          9    0.134328
6       C      1         83    1.000000
7       C      2         21    0.253012
8       C      3         36    0.433735
```

---

```
df['Normalized'] = df['Parameter'].div(df.groupby('Patient')['Parameter']
                                         .transform('first')).round(2)
print(df)
  Patient  Visit  Parameter  Normalized
0       A      1         44        1.00
1       A      2         47        1.07
2       A      3         64        1.45
3       B      1         67        1.00
4       B      2         67        1.00
5       B      3          9        0.13
6       C      1         83        1.00
7       C      2         21        0.25
8       C      3         36        0.43
```

If you need create a new DataFrame:

```
df2 = df.assign(Normalized = df['Parameter'].div(df.groupby('Patient')['Parameter'].transform('first')))
```

We could also use **lambda** as I suggested.

Or:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['Normalized'] = df['Parameter'].div(df.groupby('Patient')['Parameter']
                                         .transform('first'))
```

Comment: Many thanks! Your solution worked great in my simple example. However, when I applied it to my more complex dataset, the .transform('first') command normalized the values to some other value. However, using the same command with lambda as suggested by Christian Decker below, showed the correct values. Still have to figure out the reason for this difference, as, at least to my simple mind, the do both the same...

Comment: It was actually me who suggested using assign as well. There are no differences in this case. @Mikele

Comment: You are absolutely right. Actually, I prefer the approach without using assign and lambda. Unfortunately, I could not use in my real dataset. Do you know when it makes a difference to use one of these approaches? Or is it not possible to say that in general without a specific example?

Comment: Strange behaviour with assign vs new column name, they should be identical. Probably worth another question with minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I guess you need a new DataFrame, you can do `df2 = df.assign(Normalized = df['Parameter'].div(df.groupby('Patient')['Parameter'].transform('first')))` or  `df2=df.copy()` and then `df2['Normalized'] = df['Parameter'].div(df.groupby('Patient')['Parameter']
                                         .transform('first'))` @Mikele

Comment: @ ansev Using a new DataFrame did not help either. When I find some time, I can ask a new question with a reproducible dataset as @Evgeny suggested. The original datset contains sensitive data, so I cannot use it directly. Many thanks anyway for the comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 2):

What @ansev said: `GroupBy.transform`

If you wish to preserve the `Parameter` column, just run the last line he wrote but with `Normalized` instead of `Parameter` as the new column name:

`df = df.assign(Normalized = lambda x: x['Parameter'].div(x.groupby('Patient')['Parameter'].transform('first')))`